# Differential equation of a curve with constant product of segments

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, euclidean-geometry, circles, functional-equations, polar-coordinates

Property of a well-known continuous analytic curve is given in polar coordinates as

$$ r(\theta)\cdot r(\theta+\pi)= A $$

where $A$ is constant. Converse of the *Proposition 35 of Book 3 of Euclid's Elements,* to be now re-established by means of differential equations if not already done before.

[image: Circle segments Internal]

How do we find its differential equation in Polar or Cartesian coordinates and solve it?

By product differentiation twice with respect to $\theta$ a second order ODE

$$r(\theta)\cdot r''(\theta + \pi)+r''(\theta )\cdot r(\theta + \pi)
+2\; r^{2}(\theta)\cdot r^{'2}(\theta + \pi)=0\quad $$

with two boundary/initial conditions should procure the curve on integration.

Of relevance is may be  circle  of constant curvature familiar in polar coordinates $r= r(\theta)$ primed on $\theta$:

$$ \dfrac{r^2(\theta )
+2\; r^{'2}(\theta)- r(\theta)\cdot r''(\theta )}{[r^{'2}(\theta)+r^{'2}(\theta)]^\frac32}= \dfrac{ 1}{\sqrt{A^2+\epsilon^2}
}$$
where $\epsilon$ is an arbitrary constant.

Appreciate your indication to  approach  for analytical  solution, related links and comments.

Answer (score 1):

You don't. This is not enough information to tell much of anything about the curve.

Let $ f: [0,\pi) \to \Bbb R$ be *any function* that doesn't take on $0$ as a value. Define $$r(\theta) = \begin{cases} f(\theta),&0\le \theta < \pi\\\dfrac A{f(\theta - \pi)},&\pi\le \theta < 2\pi\end{cases}$$

and extend periodically to all of $\Bbb R$. You can prove that $r$ satisfies the equation.

Since you describe it as a curve, presumably it is continuous, in which case $f$ should be continuous and also satisfy $\lim_{\theta \to \pi-} f(\theta) = A/f(0)$. But this still leaves a vast range of possible $f$. You could even add analytic on as a condition, and still find an uncountably infinite family of functions satisfy your equation.

Comment: It is also a functional equation, Added a picture. It is among Euclid's Elements regarding the Circle, that is continuous and analytic.

Comment: Yes it is a functional equation, but even when restricted to continuous and analytic functions, *the circle is not the only function that satisfies it*. There are a vast number of shapes for which this holds true. You need more information to get a differential equation.

Comment: So the sought differential equation is expected to encompass a  number of those non-circular solution shapes including the circle... like the set of ellipses has a circle as a special case ... perhaps through an arbitrary constant.

Comment: There are too many solutions for any differential equation. Give me a family of differential equations depending on any finite number of parameters, and I can find an analytic $r$ that satisfies the function equation but does not satisfy any of the differential equations.

Comment: @Narasimham: in fact, as functional equation, it has infinitely initial conditions: all the values in the interval $[0,\pi]$